# What is this Cooper and Thief red wine bottle?

Tags: red-wine

I've got [this Cooper and Thief bottle](https://www.cooperandthief.com/). From the label, it is a blend of red wines aged in Bourbon barrils. However, unlike red wine, it is 17% alcohol.

I don't really know what to expect.

- Should I expect something sweet like a [vin cuit](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vin_cuit_(France))?

I would like to try it but I am afraid that once I open it, I will have only a few days to drink it before it becomes too oxygenated (like red wine would). Or can it be kept for a few weeks / months like a Porto wine?

- How much time do I have to drink it after opening it?

Answer (score 1):

The [CellarTracker tasting notes](https://www.cellartracker.com/notes.asp?iWine=2468631) for this one are...Interesting.  Overall it looks like it leans toward port-ish, so is probably fine for a week at least.  And if you end up thinking it is starting to degrade from oxygenation, once it's open you can throw the bottle into the freezer as you would to preserve any open wine.

Comment: Since it's 17% alcohol you need to treat it like regular wine. If it was the same strength as Port, you could enjoy it over an extended period, but it would need to be over 20% alcohol. I suspect it is a stupidly heavy red wine with some port like flavors. There are plenty of Napa cabs out there clocking in at 17% that probably taste similar.